# Markers don't show entirely on google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps

The markers seem not to be shown entirely at certain zoom levels. If I add an animation to the markers they all show ok.

**No animation:** 
[image]

**With animation:**
[image]

**Markup:**

```
 <google-map control="map.control" events="map.events" center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="map.options" draggable="{{map.draggable}}">
                    <layer ng-repeat="sa in buur.selected.areas" type="KmlLayer" options="sa.kmlOptions" ></layer>
                    <marker ng-repeat="marker in map.markers" coords="marker.coords"   options="marker.options"></marker>
   </google-map>
```

**My marker's options**  :

```
   var defaultMarker = {

                        options: {
                            icon :{
                                url: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|'+ color.substring(1),
                                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(15, 15)
                            }



                        },
                        coords: {"latitude": location.lat, "longitude": location.lng}
                    };
```

**What I tried:**  
- disabling bootstrap  
- changing the marker options  
- adding z-index to the marker option  
- refreshing the map

**Relevant Technologies used**: 
- bootstrap 3 
- angular / angular-google-maps

Comment: try 1. the [release version (v=3)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) 2. [{optimized:false}](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)

Comment: {optimized:false}  it worked! Thanks.